# Getting work experience from facebook API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, facebook-android-sdk

I want to fetch the Work Experience of the User who logged into my app.
The Facebook SDK documentation is not quite descriptive as in what particularly I need to use in the place of "work-experience-id".

Here is my code in `onSuccess` method

```
new GraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken().getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "/work", null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("Facebook", response.toString());
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

Please help. It would be a great help

Comment: `work` is not an Edge, but just a Field. `/me?fields=work`

Comment: Yeah, If you have any idea about android-sdk, cause doc is showing different example

Comment: What example? Be specific, and give a link.

Comment: @CBroe https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/work-experience/ this

Comment: That is not a “different example”, it is simply the second step. You need to request `/me?fields=work` to _get_ those work experience ids.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for this, unfortunately, Facebook no longer returns this data. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/user

[image: Facebook API reference]